# Bootstrap 4: how to animate button changing margin-top without moving rows below?

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

I have two rows, one with a button and one with text, I want to add a simple animation on the button by changing it's margin-top, problem is that all the rows below will move with the button. I tried with position-absolute on button and position-relative on col, but then bootstrap columns don't wrap in responsive.

```
button:active {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <button>
        <p>Button</p>
      </button>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <button>
        <p>Text.</p>
      </button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust the appearance of an element without adjusting how it affects the rest of the page, use the [`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). In this case you want to move in the y-direction so use [`translateY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY):

```
button:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```